# Ajax event is not working properly

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

The button  with ajax call

```
$form['add_product_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Add product'),
   // '#submit' => array('uc_order_pane_products_select'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'uc_order_pane_products_ajax_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'product-controls',
    ),
  );
```

### ajax function

function uc_order_pane_products_ajax_callback($form, &$form_state) {

```
 $newtable = uc_order_product_select_form();
 $commands[] = ajax_command_prepend('#product-controls', render($newtable));
 return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
 }
```

### function--uc_order_product_select_form()

function uc_order_product_select_form()
            {

```
       $form['new_order'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title'=>t(' Quantiy'),
         );

       $form['new_order']['add_order_text'] = array(
         '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#title' => t('Add Quantity'),
          );

               $form['new_order']['select_div'] = array(
                '#type' => 'submit',
                '#submit'=> 'uc_order_pane_products_ajax_callback1',
                '#value' => t('Add to Order'),
              // '#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'return uc_order_pane_products_ajax_callback1;'),
                   '#ajax'=>array(
                            'callback' => 'uc_order_pane_products_ajax_callback1',
                            'wrapper' => 'product-controls',
                              ),
                 );
        return $form;
      }

function uc_order_pane_products_ajax_callback1()
{
  print "success";
}
```

Comment: what is the framework you are using?

Comment: @Abdo Adel  drupal 7

Comment: Your uc_order_product_select_form() function does not return $form. Also, "is not working properly" is not enough information. Please describe in detail what happens, what error messages you receive (if any), and what you want to happen.

Comment: @BrianShowalter Sry, I forgot the return, and this is my code. I just want to print the value from textfield add quantity( t('Add Quantity') ).

Comment: OK, that describes what you want to do.  What happens when you try to run your code? Need details on the latter.

Comment: @BrianShowalter   When I clicked the  button ( t('Add to Order')) the page reloaded.